# Terraform: Host key verification failed

Tags: terraform

When I try to clone a repo from a module I get the following error

```
module "rsgr-05" {  
source     ="git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v5/xxxx-devops/DevOps/terraform-azure?ref=firstversion"  
rsgr_loc   = var.location  
infr-env   = var.infr-env  
audit      = var.audit  
seq_number = "002"}
```

```
Could not download module "rsgr-05" (main.tf:12) source code from
"git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v5/xxxx-devops/DevOps/terraform-azure?ref=firstversion":
error downloading
'ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v5/xxxx-devops/DevOps/terraform-azure?ref=firstversion':
/usr/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into '.terraform/modules/rsgr-05'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

As I am deploying from an azure devops agent, understanding that it does not have the ssh key and that is why it fails.
Is there a way to generate an ssh key and upload it via command line to azure devops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Generate a new ssh key.
2. Grant it access to Azure Devops by adding it as READ ONLY access under your account.
3. Add the ssh key as a secure file in your pipelines library (where variable groups are)
4. Use InstallSSHKey@0 in your pipeline before Terraform runs to install the ssh key.
5. Refence your module on an Azure Devops project with the right url structure.

Your module should look like this:

```
module foo {
source = "git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/<Org>/<Project>/<Repo>//<FolderPath>?ref=<TagOrBranch>"
}
```